# set-azureaduser setting companyname with powershell

Tags: azure-active-directory

I am trying to set companyname for a given user in Azure AD. I havent been able to find any samples with set-azureadusercompanyname, can anyone provide a sample?

Comment: see if this helps https://serverfault.com/questions/894374/update-the-companyname-attribute-for-an-azure-ad-user-via-powershell

Comment: Ohh I hope not:( Looks like you can only do its from sync from onpremise. In this case there is not an onpremise AD.

Comment: As jason said in that answer, we cannot set the company for users in AAD.

Comment: Roger, thanks for you reply. Its appreciated!

Comment: jason can make an answer.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you want to set this attribute?

Comment: I want to create a test environment similar to customer. I have a MVC app where i need to use this property to determine what kind of business user who is logged into the MVC application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the ServerFault link above, you can set this (I have tested) using:

```
Set-AzureADUserExtension -ObjectId <UPN> -ExtensionName "CompanyName" -ExtensionValue "<VALUE>"
```

In fact how I did it was:

```
Get-AzureADUser -SearchString user.name | Set-AzureADUserExtension -ExtensionName "CompanyName" -ExtensionValue "Company Name"
```